# How to check that cache is working correctly?

Tags: django, memcached, telnet, amazon-elasticache

I've just created a `Memcache` cluster using Amazon's Elasticache service. I have a django app that points to this cache and am experimenting with some simple template caching. My caching in `django` is as follows:

```
{% load cache %}

{% cache 600 test_page %}
 ....
{% endcache %}
```

Is there a simple way for me to check if this fragment exists in Elasticache? I've looked through the AWS [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/GettingStarted.ConnectToCacheNode.Memcached.html), and understand how to connect to the instance using the following steps:

1 - Log into an EC2 instance:

2 - install telnet

```
sudo apt-get install telnet
```

3 - connect

```
telnet mycache.cfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com 11211
```

This enables me to login to the cache, but I don't understand how I would go about checking to see if this cache fragment exists.

Comment: Why not just put a timestamp in the cached area and see if it changes? If you want to dig around in memcached, there's plenty of examples online for how to reveal statistics. Checking if that cache fragment exists through MC will require help from django to get the generated cache key: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#django.core.cache.utils.make_template_fragment_key

Comment: How would I add a timestamp to the cache? And is it possible to then pull out anything with a particular timestamp?

Comment: Insert a python datetime object into your template. Render it in an area thats supposed to be cached. If the date doesn't change between page reloads, it's obviously cached.